# Setting a parameter inside a date

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm writing a script in SQL Server that should insert some data (DUH).

My problem is that the MONTH of the date (the one in bold) has to be SET every time to a different month.

It should be something like '2011-@month-27', but that doesn't work of course.

Here's the script:

```
USE xxx

DECLARE @Month int;
DECLARE @DateToCopy datetime;

SET **@Month = 09**  -- The month
SET @DateToCopy = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-10-27 00:00:00', 102)  -- The date to copy

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO Z_T_CurrencyRate_Test (CurrencyID, RateDate, RateToMain, RateToSec, CurrencyRate)
    SELECT CurrencyID, **CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-10-27 00:00:00', 102)**, RateToMain, RateToSec, CurrencyRate 
    FROM T_CurrencyRate
    WHERE (RateDate = @DateToCopy)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Are you trying to move data from `T_CurrencyRate` into `Z_T_CurrencyRate_Test`, based on the month of column RateDate?

Comment: what if the date does not belong to the month say for instance month is 02 and date is 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to specify the *month* part of the date/time, while keeping *day* and *year* the same.

Here's a method to modify the current month value to a new one:

```
DATEADD(month, -DATEPART(month, RateDate) + @Month, RateDate)
```

The above code will *subtract* the current month, and *add* the new one; essentially replacing the *month* part of the date/time. Please note that `RateDate` is the column/variable that you wish to have its month changed.

The functions used above are [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) (adds/subtracts an integer value to a specific part of a date/time; month, day, year, hour, etc.) and [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) (extracts a specific date/time part; month, day, year, etc.).

---

Per the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158475/setting-a-parameter-inside-a-date/16158596?noredirect=1#comment23130221_16158596), here's how to insert the information for every day of the month:

```
USE xxx

DECLARE @DateToCopy datetime;
DECLARE @Month int;
DECLARE @LastDay int;
DECLARE @CurrentDay int;

SET @DateToCopy = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-10-27 00:00:00', 102);  -- The date to copy
SET @Month = 09;  -- The month
SET @LastDay = DATEPART(day, DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(day, @DateToCopy), DATEADD(month, 1, @DateToCopy)));

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET @CurrentDay = 1;
WHILE (@CurrentDay <= @Lastday)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Z_T_CurrencyRate_Test (CurrencyID, RateDate, RateToMain, RateToSec, CurrencyRate)
    SELECT
        CurrencyID,
        DATEADD(month, -DATEPART(month, RateDate) + @Month, DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(day, RateDate) + @CurrentDay, RateDate)), -- important bit!
        RateToMain,
        RateToSec,
        CurrencyRate
    FROM T_CurrencyRate
    WHERE (RateDate = @DateToCopy);

    SET @CurrentDay = @CurrentDay + 1;
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**Here's what the first new mess will do:**

```
SET @LastDay = DATEPART(
                         day,
                         DATEADD(
                                  day,
                                  -DATEPART(day, @DateToCopy),
                                  DATEADD(month, 1, @DateToCopy)
                                )
                       );
```

From left-to-right (however, do note that because of nesting, calculations happen backwards):

1. `DATEPART(day, ...)` will extract the calculated day (which will be the last day of the month).
2. `DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(day, @DateToCopy), ...)` subtracts the current number of days.

   - e.g., `2011-10-27` - `27` = `2011-09-30`.
3. `DATEADD(month, 1, @DateToCopy)` simply jumps over to the next month, to the perform the subtraction from # 2.

**And the second new mess:**

```
DATEADD(
         month,
         -DATEPART(month, RateDate) + @Month,
         DATEADD(
                  day,
                  -DATEPART(day, RateDate) + @CurrentDay,
                  RateDate
                )
       ), -- important bit!
```

Again, from left-to-right, and calculated backwards (due to nesting):

1. `DATEADD(month, ..., ...)` will replace the month from `RateDate`.
2. `-DATEPART(month, RateDate) + @Month` is the *calculated* replacement month.
3. `DATEADD(day, ..., RateDate)` will replace the day from `RateDate`.
4. `-DATEPART(day, RateDate) + @CurrentDay` is the *calculated* replacement date.

Comment: That's a good solution, thanks. Only thing is, I need the day to be specified (not taken from the RateDate).

Ideally, it would insert into EVERY day of that month. So if the month is 09, it would insert the same lines into 2011-09-01, 2011-09-02 and etc.

I planned to achieve it, by duplicating the same query and just putting a different day every time, but probably there's a smarter way... :)

Comment: @VladiTrop Ok, I think I understand - so basically you want to update the *month* part of the date/time for a specific month? For example, you want to change all entries for the month of April (04) to be the month of September (09)?

Comment: @VladiTrop I've updated my answer - hopefully that gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, it's almost that. I will start from scratch:
A user fills in the rate on the 1st April 2012, the only thing I need to do is to put the same rate for ALL the days of THAT month.
So it will just copy the values from 1st April, insert a new line with the same details, but with 2nd April, then with 3rd April and etc.

Comment: @VladiTrop How does the data get *to* SQL from the user? Is it through a stored procedure, parametrized query, etc.?

Comment: If I will put DateToCopy same month as to where I want to copy. Then your solution above will do just that, no?

Comment: The user fills it in, in the software. I don't know exactly the answer to your question. But I know that it will appear in that table after he saved it in the software.

Comment: @VladiTrop Correct. Set `@DateToCopy` to *any* day inside of the desired month, but making sure that the entry exists in the `T_CurrencyRate` table, and the SQL statement in the answer will take care of everything for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I will test it tomorrow morning and will let you know.

Comment: @VladiTrop For example, if the user selects `1st April 2012`, **make sure** that you set `@DateToCopy` to be `2012-04-01 00:00:00`

Comment: Works great! Thanks again.
Unrelated question: Is it possible to somehow block some chunks of the code to be modified by the user? (to protect it). So I want only the month and the ratetocopy to be possible to change.

Comment: @VladiTrop The *easiest* way to achieve that is by not giving the user access to the database, and running that code from a program. If that's not possible, next best thing is to create a stored procedure with just those parameters, and deny the user's login from modifying stored procedures. Other than that, no, there's really no way.

Answer (score 0):

You just want your **month** to be **different** every time. You just need to do as follows:

```
SELECT CurrencyID, 
CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-'+ @Month+'-27 00:00:00', 102), RateToMain, 
RateToSec, CurrencyRate 
FROM T_CurrencyRate
```

You just need to `concatenate`.

Comment: That almost works, thanks. Only thing is when I insert 12, it will insert it as 1. It just takes the first digit..

Comment: Try this, hope it will work
`CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-'+CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(50))+'-27 00:00:00', 102)`